# Problema al descifrar imagen con RSA

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de descifrar una imagen que ha sido cifrada mediante RSA. Sin embargo, al hacer el descifrado y abrir la imagen obtengo un error indicando que el contenido está corrupto o no es válido

El código para hacer el cifrado y descifrado es el siguiente

```py
def generar_claves() -> list[RSA.RsaKey, RSA.RsaKey]:
    """
    :return [private_key, public_key]
    """
    private_key = RSA.generate(2048)
    public_key = private_key.publickey()

    return [private_key, public_key]

def cifrar_imagen(bytes_img:bytes, filename:str, public_key_:str) -> None:
    public_key = RSA.import_key(public_key_)
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key)
    stream_bytes = BytesIO(bytes_img)

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        fragmento = stream_bytes.read(200)
        while fragmento:
            fragmento_cifrado = cipher.encrypt(fragmento)
            f.write(fragmento_cifrado)
            fragmento = stream_bytes.read(200)    

def decifrar_imagen(filename:str, private_key_:str) -> None:
    private_key = RSA.import_key(private_key_)
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)

    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        # Abrimos el archivo donde guardaremos el archivo descifrado
        with open('archivo_descifrado.png', 'wb') as g:
            # Leemos el archivo cifrado por fragmentos de 256 bytes
            fragmento = f.read(256)
            while fragmento:
                fragmento_descifrado = cipher.decrypt(fragmento)
                g.write(fragmento_descifrado)
                fragmento = f.read(256)
```

Luego uso esas fuciones para crear las llaves y junto con la librería PIL habro la imagen, obtengo los bytes y la cifro, finalmente la descifro y guardo.

```py
priv, pub = generar_claves()
priv_key = priv.export_key()
pub_key = pub.export_key()

img = Image.open('imagen.png')
bytes_img = img.tobytes()

cifrar_imagen(bytes_img, 'imagen.bin', pub_key)
decifrar_imagen('imagen.bin', priv_key)
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Estás utilizando la librería `cryptography` o alguna otra?

Comment: uso `pycryptodome`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no es de la librería criptográfica, sino de que lo que estás cifrando es el resultado de un `Image.open().tobytes()` y eso descomprime el archivo PNG para acceder a sus pixeles "raw".

Eso por un lado va a hacer que el cifrado tarde mucho más (pues son muchos más bytes una vez los has descomprimido via PIL), y que el resultado .bin sea muy grande (pues son el cifrado de una imagen descomprimida). Y por otro lado que al descifrar la imagen con decrypt, además de tardar mucho, el resultado sea una imagen descomprimida PIL, la cual no puedes guardar "sin más" en un .png, sino que sería necesario de nuevo usar PIL para convertirla en PNG.

Es decir, en el fondo, si quitamos el crypt/decrypt tu problema es que estás haciendo el equivalente a lo siguiente:

```
img = Image.open('imagen.png')
bytes_img = img.tobytes()
with open("resultado.png", "wb") as f:
  f.write(bytes_img)
```

Eso produce un fichero de extensión `.png` pero su contenido no es realmente png, sino una representación binaria de la imagen descomprimida ("raw" podríamos decir) en un formato interno de PIL.

### Solución

La solución es **no usar PIL** aquí. A las funciones de cifrado/descifrado les da lo mismo si lo que les pasas es un png o cualquier otra cosa. Solo son bytes. Así que lee los bytes del fichero sin PIL, así:

```
priv, pub = generar_claves()
priv_key = priv.export_key()
pub_key = pub.export_key()

with open('imagen.png') as f:
    bytes_img = f.read()

cifrar_imagen(bytes_img, 'imagen.bin', pub_key)
decifrar_imagen('imagen.bin', priv_key)
```